# displaying String in webview

Tags: objective-c, xcode, webview

I'm trying to display a set of strings to a webview, I know it can be done, I try to create my own html for it,

```
[contentWebView loadHTMLString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<html><head><link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"default.css\" type=\"text/css\" /><script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"default.js\"></script></head><body%@>%@</body></html>", cssFontSizeOverride, webcontent] baseURL:nil];
```

but the result, it never show anything, I'm just having a blank page. Any one know how to troubleshoot this? Thanx in advance.

Comment: Do you have the referred css (in ur html)files in your app? Just check with a simple HTML string.

Comment: I think you need to set the *baseURL*.

Comment: @krishan: I did put a default.css file in my resources.

Answer (score 0):

You're referencing external resources with relative URLs (default.css, default.js). Those can only be loaded if you provide a base URL.

Comment: as for the base URL, what should I input in it? Is there any specific link I need to put?

Comment: Depends on where your resources are located. If you have them locally, you could create a file URL with [NSURL fileURLWithPath:...].

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at:

- [Linking to a local HTML file with links to JS and CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5430279/linking-to-a-local-html-file-with-links-to-js-and-css/5430320#5430320)
- [Loading javascript into a UIWebView from resources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5733883/loading-javascript-into-a-uiwebview-from-resources)